# Что такое пул в php-fpm?

Tags: php, php-fpm

В php-fpm по умолчанию, сразу после установки есть пул www. Все об этом знают и надеюсь понимают, но я не совсем. Примерно понимаю что это типа выделенная группа процессов php-fpm. Может быть наверное несколько пулов.

Кто-то может объяснить или дать ссылку на документацию где объясняется что такое пул php-fpm и зачем он нужен? Сам я путем гугления не нашёл.

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: хороший вопрос. Наш сисадмин использовал для каждого сайта свой пул под своим юзером. Так он разграничивал настройки потоков и т.д. плюс разграничения по пользователям. т.е. если вдруг взломали один сайт то взломщик не сможет повредить другим сайтам.

Comment: Так всё-таки что это? Наверное от swiming-pool=бассейн, это какая-то область процессов php-fpm, к которой можно применить свои настройки. Например запустить от определённого юзера, ограничить максимальное кол-во процессов пула и т.д. ???

Answer (score 15):

Пулы php-fpm - позволяют запускать процессы php под разными пользователями, тем самым создавая более безопасную среду.
Так же, каждому пулу - можно выделять свои ресурсы и переопределять переменные php.ini

Например:
Для `production` версии сайта - один пул, для `development` версии сайта - другой пул.

Каждый пул работает или на отдельном порте, или на отдельном сокет файле. Как утверждают некоторые мануалы по оптимизации php-fpm - то для сайта с высокой нагрузкой разумней использовать несколько пулов.

Цитата:

`In our experience, multiple upstream backends on the same machine, produce higher throughout than a single one.`

Comment: Благодарю! Ясно!

Answer (score 9):

Пул (pool) в программировании - это контейнер для повторно используемых ресурсов. Он используется для экономии на создании ресурса. Идея в том, что после завершения использования ресурса он не уничтожается - а возвращается в пул, откуда его можно быстро достать для повторного использования.

Не следует путать пул и кэш - хотя их назначение и схоже, но в кэше хранятся *разные* объекты, в пуле же все ресурсы абсолютно одинаковы (смысл пула как раз в том чтобы ресурс, взятый из пула, никак не отличался от только что созданного).

---

К примеру, открытие соединения с БД - операция долгая, поскольку надо устанавливать сетевое соединение. Поэтому соединения с БД часто объединяют в пулы соединений.

Создание нового потока - операция дорогая. Поэтому библиотеки, предназначенные для асинхронной работы, часто содержат пул потоков. А на винде пул потоков даже является частью WinAPI.

В случае php-fpm, каждый запрос обрабатывается в некотором процессе. Запуск процесса - операция еще более дорогая чем создание потока - а потому используются пулы процессов.

Ну а поскольку в случае с php-fpm может потребоваться создавать разные процессы (с разными настройками), а один пул может содержать только одинаковые ресурсы - php-fpm создает несколько пулов, каждый со своими настройками. Вот так настройки процесса стали настройками пула, а пул из паттерна программирования стал единицей администрирования.

Comment: Теперь всё ясно, благодарю! )